# Webpack inserts unwanted space after certain Turkish characters

Tags: css, webpack, character-encoding, less, turkish

Webpack inserts an unwanted space after certain Turkish characters.  In the following example, a space is inserted after ç in "se**ç**eceğiniz" and after ğ in "ma**ğ**azamızdan":

[image]

```
  &[data-slug='RetailStore']:after {
    content: "Siparişinizde yer alan ürünleri, seçeceğiniz mağazamızdan 2-3 iş günü içinde teslim alabilirsiniz.";
    display: block !important;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 5px 0 8px;
  }

"Sipari\15Finizde yer alan \FCr\FCnleri, se\E7  ece\11Finiz ma\11F  azam\131zdan 2-3 i\15F   g\FCn\FC   i\E7inde teslim alabilirsiniz."
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening?